# How can resolve conflicts Dart SDK binary

Tags: flutter, dart

I need help. When I type the command “ **brew info dart** “ It’s look like dart has a conflict with beta version, the current version is 2.9.3.
How can delete the old version or the both?

[image]

Comment: `brew uninstall dart-beta`

Comment: @Abion47 I tried It’s saying: “ No installed keg or cask with the name dart-beta

Comment: Then you're fine. No installed `dart-beta` means no conflict.

Comment: So I can say It’s thank you

Answer (score 0):

use

/usr/local/opt/dart/libexec

at dart SDK configuration path

Answer (score 0):

My issue was that I had installed my own version of Dart using brew. This is what causes the error. Because Flutter is installed with a version of Dart.

All you need to do is run `brew uninstall dart`